# How to syntax highlight a content-editable div without external libraries?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make a web text editor that has live syntax highlighting like **Visual Studio Code** but the problem is when I try to highlight, it puts my cursor in the back of the editor.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Code</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #code {
            background:#2b2e33;
            color:white;
            font-family:Monaco;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="code" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("code");
        setInterval(function() {
            var code = div.innerText;
            code = code.replace("var","<span style='color:magenta'>var</span>");
            div.innerHTML = code;
        },100)
    </script>
</body>
```

The cursor seems to go to the back and the text is being reversed for no apparent reason...

Comment: You can try this (I haven't tried) - You can store the current cursor position. Update the div. Update the cursor position. This is a gist that I came across that might help you achieve the get/set functions for the contenteditable div. ==> https://gist.github.com/isLishude/6ccd1fbf42d1eaac667d6873e7b134f8   |  Let me know too incase you're able to fix this issue. I couldn't get time to dig deeper into this.

Comment: Also this medium articles seems to be focusing on the same issue https://medium.com/compass-true-north/a-dancing-caret-the-unknown-perils-of-adjusting-cursor-position-f252734f595e | Hope it helps

Comment: @SivcanSingh how would I use caret.js, it looks very confusing and there is no usage at all?